# External-IP visible outside kubernetes-cluster

Tags: ubuntu, networking, kubernetes, proxy, kubernetes-ingress

I create LoadBalancer service(test) for kubernetes-cluster.

[image]

From cluster it is possible to curl website via service, curl 192.168.33.112 or curl localhost:30797.

But outside the cluster(from our cloud subnet), it is only possible to access it by curl "masterIP":30797.

What i m supposed to do, have a visible service outside the cluster(curl 192.168.33.112).

Comment: How did you run the nginx ingress controller? Can you provide the deployment file you used?

Comment: helm install nginx-ingress stable/nginx-ingress --set controller.publishService.enabled=true

Comment: What cloud is it? And where did you get the EXTERNAL-IP from?

Comment: i created pool of external-IP by https://opensource.com/article/20/7/homelab-metallb .
Internal Cloud everything by our hands .

Comment: how is possible to route created IP outside this cluster ??